# LESS css not compiling on local Apache VirtualHost

Tags: less

I'm serving a site from two local URLs..

**localhost/mysite (using an alias)**

**local.mysite.com (using an virtual host)**

They point to the same directory. However, the first one compiles my .less files fine, while the second one doesn't. Does anybody know why this would be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Less has different optimization rules for development vs. production environments. It defines a development environment as anything being served from 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', or '0.0.0.0' with everything else being considered production. Since my virtual host uses a different domain, Less considers it a prod environment and doesn't continually re-parse the .less files.